# Incorporating JSON from Google Maps API Wizard into existing html

Tags: json, api, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to customize the base map for a google fusion table.  I'm using the Maps API Style Wizard and have created the map I want, but I'm at a loss as to how to incorporate the JSON code generated by the Map wizard into the html code for the existing page:

This is the map I'd like to customize: http://shatterbe.lt/ses_maps/per_capita_upper_eastside.html

And this is the code that the API Map wizard gave me:

```
[
  {
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "simplified" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Someone help?  I know the answer is probably very simple, but I'm new to all of this!

Comment: Did you refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)?  Did the example there not help?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.826923725271442, -80.18369569667362),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    styles: [
       {
         "stylers": [
           { "visibility": "simplified" }
         ]
       },{
        "featureType": "road.highway",
         "stylers": [
          { "visibility": "off" }
         ]
       }
    ],
    heatmap: { enabled: false },
    query: {
      select: "col6",
      from: "1_atSM8PGxxDThZlVGvFw4WlyaYHKuXU9CoCvGU0",
      where: ""
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });
}
```

[Documentation describing how to add styling to the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#styling_the_default_map)

[Example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple)

Comment: So I tried to incorporate the map style code as you've done here (thank you!), but the map still looks the same.  What I'm looking for is a simplified base map with no labels, street names, etc., but I don't see those changes.  Do you see street labels, etc.?

Comment: [This](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_per_capita_upper_eastsideA.html) is what I see.

Comment: That's perfect!  I'll go back and check my coding, as mine still looks like this: http://www.shatterbe.lt/ses_maps/per_capita_upper_eastside_test.html

Comment: Looks the same to me.  Either you fixed it or you have an older version of the page stuck in your browser's cache.

Comment: I fixed it.  Thanks so much for your help, geocodezip.  It is much appreciated!

Comment: Absolutely!  just did - sorry for the delay, new to the system.