# Where do I add JSON into Google Maps Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I have this script for Google Maps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.523612, -0.125816),
          zoom: 17,

        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

and this JSON:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      { "saturation": -100 },
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "stylers": [
      { "saturation": -100 }
    ]
  },{
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
  }
]
```

How do I combine them to give the style I'm looking for?

I can't seem to find the right documentation.

Comment: It seems to me this JSON describes map options, so it should be included in the mapOptions variable. Have you tried this?

Comment: Besides, your mapOptions variable is being initialized with a comma in the end of it ( after zoom = 17 ) that should be taken away, unless you are going to write something after it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incorporating JSON from Google Maps API Wizard into existing html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029606/incorporating-json-from-google-maps-api-wizard-into-existing-html/17030627#17030627)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example [from Google](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/maptype-styled-iframe) that shows you how to integrate the various elements together.

```
  var styles =   [
    {
      stylers: [
        { hue: '#00ffe6' },
        { saturation: -20 }
      ]
    },{
      featureType: 'road',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [
        { lightness: 100 },
        { visibility: 'simplified' }
      ]
    },{
      featureType: 'road',
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [
        { visibility: 'off' }
      ]
    }
  ];

  // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
  // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
  var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
    {name: 'Styled Map'});

  // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
  // to the map type control.
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.9818, -114.1219),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, 'styled_maps']
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  // Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
  map.mapTypes.set('styled_maps', styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('styled_maps');
}
```